# Webpack not bundling .json file in node_modules properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron, raspberry-pi3

I am currently building an electron app to deploy on a raspberry pi3 with a react front end. It's using webpack to bundle everything. I am also trying to use the node-raspicam package to interact with the camera module. I have successfully been able to use the node-raspbicam package on it's own outside of this app. But when I try to import it in this application I get the following error 

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../options in /usr/src/app/node_modules/raspicam/lib
@ ./~/raspicam/lib/raspicam.js 7:17-38 8:12-33`

in raspicam.js it tries to do `parameters = require("../options").parameters` which is where it is failing. 
In the raspicam tree within node_modules options.json exists one directory up from where it is being called.

My thought is webpack is not bundling this json file properly therefore, it cannot be found.

My webpack loaders :

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
      loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
      include: path.images
    },
     {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    packageMains: ['webpack', 'browser', 'web', 'browserify', ['jam', 'main'], 'main']
  },
  plugins: [

  ],
  externals: [
    // put your node 3rd party libraries which can't be built with webpack here
    // (mysql, mongodb, and so on..)
  ]
```

I am still fairly new to webpack. What am I missing so that the options.json file in the raspicam node_module gets bundled properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `.json` to the `extensions` in the `resolve` object in the config file. It may work.